# Why do I get the Maximum call stack size exceeded error. Without .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I am trying to make a following feature when I try to use the follow button I get "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" If I add `.val()` to the end of `Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$addToSet: {'profile.following': usern}});` It returns `" "` to `profile.following` where it should return the username of the profile the user is on. Thanks in advanced here is the code.

```
    Template.user_profile.events({
     'click #follow':function () {
        var usern=$("#username");
        Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$addToSet: {'profile.following': usern}});
        return Meteor.user().profile.following;
    }
})
```

html

```
  <template name="user_profile">
  <h2 id="username">{{username}}</h2>
  <div>{{profile.followingnumber}}</div>
  <div>{{profile.followedbynumber}}</div>
  <div>{{profile.bio}}</div>
  <button id="follow">Follow</button>
</template>
```

server side

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(user) {
    user.profile.following=[];
    user.profile.followingn=0;
    user.profile.followed=[];
    user.profile.followedn=0;
    return user;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside an event handler, you can access the current data context using `this`, so instead of accessing the user profile username by `jQuery` (you should have used `$("#username").text()`, `.val()` is for form elements only !), simply use `this.username`.

So this is what you should come up with :

```
Template.user_profile.events({
  "click #follow":function(){
    Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(),{
      $addToSet:{
        "profile.following": this.username
      }
    });
  }
});
```

There is no particular need to return the current user following list in this click event, not sure what you intended in the first place.